# AngularJs - Holding value of for loop string to use elsewhere

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, for-loop

I've come a bit stuck in my angularjs project.

I run a for loop to query some nested JSON data and output it in 3 different variables inside an ng-repeat. So it makes up a title where i have the control over the elements that make up the title {{ number }} {{ shots }} {{ goals }}.

However, my knowledge of angularjs is stretched here because when I click on one of the events (from the ng-repeat list) it gives me a new tab, but I want to bring the title of that event to the new tab.

I can't call it as a scope variable as the last variable is still being held in there. I thought about assigning it as a new variable.. but was unsure how to actually do that in angularjs.

Here is the code i'm working with:

```
<li ng-repeat="event in events.events">
        <div ng-if="actionType(event)" >
           {{number}}
           {{shots}}
           {{goals}}
        </div>

    <a class="showPlayer" ng-click="showPlayer(event)">
           View more stats
    </a>
</li>
```

my angularjs is just a standard for loop which looks for values inside the js and assigns them as variables.

Any advice is very much appreciated.

EDIT: 24 hours later and I still can't crack this (very frustrating).
I'm not sure if there is a way to grab the string from the ng-click and clone that?
I don't want to have to run another check for the title when I already have the information, surely there is an 'angular' way to do this??

Answer (score 0):

Please try this I am not sure but it might help you

```
 <li ng-repeat="event in events.events">
           <div ng-if="actionType(event)" >
               {{event.number}}
               {{event.shots}}
               {{event.goals}}
           </div>

        <a class="showPlayer" ng-click="showPlayer(event.number,event.shots,event.goals)">
               View more stats
        </a>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24rootScope).
Define a rootscope variable where event is handled and write your title in html like you did. {{title}}

```
$rootScope.title = "example";
```

Comment: if i just output {{ shots }} for e.g. then it just uses the last string assigned to that variable no matter which one I click. E.g. if the for loop produced 0, 5, 6, 3, 4 and i clicked on 6. {{ shots }} always outputs 4. It's as if I need to grab the information for the selected event.